# Apache virtual host loads wrong page when a path is used

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I have a number of virtual hosts setup on my Apache server (RedHat) that all work fine until a path is used. To explain.

I have:

- https: //myserver1.com (default site)
- https: //myserver2.com
- https: //myserver3.com

But when a user lands on any of them they get the correct page and the URL is appended to /PORTAL/STARTUP.php

But if the users then bookmark their page e.g. https: //myserver3.com/PORTAL/STARTUP.php they will land of the default site but with the correct URL.

What have I missed?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myserver1
    ServerName myserver1. com
    ErrorLog logs/myserver1-error_log
    CustomLog logs/myserver1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myserver2
    ServerName myserver2.com
    ErrorLog logs/myserver2-error_log
    CustomLog logs/myserver2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myserver3
    ServerName myserver3.com
    ErrorLog logs/myserver3_error_log
    CustomLog logs/myserver3_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
        ServerAlias *
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
        ServerAlias *
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=301]
</VirtualHost>

<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|png)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>

Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: "master-only"
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName clientA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog logs/clientA.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientA.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName clientB.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect / https://clientB.com/
    ErrorLog logs/clientB.error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientB.access_log common
</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:443>
   # DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientC
    #ServerName www.clientC.com
    #ErrorLog logs/clientB.com-error_log
    #CustomLog logs/clientB.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientD
    ServerName clientD.com
    ErrorLog logs/clientD.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientD.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientE
    ServerName clientE.com
    ErrorLog logs/clientD.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientD.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientF
    ServerName clientF.com
    ErrorLog logs/clientF.com_error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientF.com_access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientG
  ServerName clientG.com
  ErrorLog logs/clientG_error_log
  CustomLog logs/clientG_access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientH
    ServerName clientH.com
    ErrorLog logs/clientH_error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientH_access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientI
    ServerName clientI.com
    ErrorLog logs/clientI_error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientI_access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clientJ
    ServerName clientJ.com
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://111.111.111.111/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://11.111.111.111/
    ServerName clientK.com
    ErrorLog logs/clientK_error_log
    CustomLog logs/clientK_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the above vhost entries go on to clients through to J

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It seems that going to any of the three servers would redirect you to the same server but to the `/PORTAL/STARTUP.php` page (either by a rewrite rule on apache or by a index page with a `<meta refresh>`). Bookmarks set by the browser can only happen when you finish loading the page, so any jump will always be skipped. If you want that your clients bookmark your site with a certain URL, you could do it 2 ways: a) set a javascript to save the bookmark to whatever you want. b) do not make the redirect visible to the user.

Comment: Thanks NuTTyX, so to rephrase:<br/>

in the www/html folder I have 3 sites:<br/>

Site1<br/>
Site2<br/>
Site3<br/>

My virtual hosts //myserver1.com //myserver2.com //myserver3.com all point to those site folders.<br/>

But the URL adds /PORTAL/STARTUP.php to the end of the URL.<br/>

If the user bookmarks //myserver3.com/PORTAL/STARTUP.php they are presented the URL //myserver3.com/PORTAL/STARTUP.php but the site is actually Site1 not Site3.<br/>

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Also how would I make the redirect invisible to the user?

Comment: How do you redirect the users to the `STARTUP.php` page? RewriteRule, <meta>, or some other way? I see you are refering to https://, are you using a single cert valid to the 3 sites or relying on SNI? As for not showing the full URL to the user, there are a few ways: easiest is to put a frame around (index.html has a frame/iframe to the STARTUP). Another one would be creating a index.php including STARTUP to act as a entry point, but you may need to tweak a little your site. Lastly, by using RewriteRule on apache, but it would require some work and depends heavily on your site design.

Comment: Not really sure how it gets there, essentially there are 3 files that are used.

index.php, startup.php and login_template.htm 

this is the contents of the index file:

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) {
 header("Location: ".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
 exit();
}
require_once("PORTAL/STARTUP.php");
?>

Comment: and we have a mix of SNI and certificates for specific sites.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the server name in the bookmark does not match the name in the ServerName directive, thus falling to the first VirtualHost (the default). I assume that you have 3 VirtualHost with the same IP:port (or *:port) in each, or maybe are you using a hostname there (i.e. <VirtualHost server1.com:443>)? It is pretty strange that the first entry arrives correctly, so my guess is that there are some issues with the hostname resolution. Could you please show me your configuration of VirtualHost and ServerName/ServerAlias in their current order? (Fake ip/names are ok)

Comment: Hi NuTTyX, happy to share, is there a way I can get it to you or do a screen share or something else? is it only the virtual host section you need or the whole config file?

Comment: I mean the whole config reduced to the lines containing VirtualHost, ServerName and ServerAlias. For privacy reasons change the real IP/name for fake ones, but be consitent (realIP1 <-> fakeIP1 in every case)

Comment: NuTTyX I have put it in the update above as it was very long.

Comment: I see a few strange things: first two VH are the same and have a VA with a wildcard, so the second won't be used at all. VH clientA will also not execute if reached by IP 111.111.111.111 (will be served by 1st VH instead since the VA * there will take it). Redirect on VH clientB will cause a loop (destination of redirect is the same SN and the same URI) or will not work at all (not sure if it takes precedence over the ServerIndex or not) . Did you include the VH that didn't work? Your question talked about three https sites, so maybe there're some misconfiguration on the other VH.

Comment: Hiya, well there are 11 sites in total, I'll stick it all in there for you but the follow a common theme.

Comment: Just until the one you have problems with will be enough

Comment: Probably worth noting that I inherited this and am no Linux expert at present.

Comment: They all suffer the same problem actually, so the software redirects the user to /PORTAL/Startup.php

Comment: Which server were you having problems with? I see problems with the following VH: ClientA (will not receive anything if reached by 111.111.111.111), clientB (redirect creates a loop), clientC (it is commented out) and clientK (the proxypass creates a loop between clientK and the 1st VH) will not work properly.